# Efficiency for Path.GetFileName storing in a string or reusing method call

Tags: c#, winforms

I am just very curious to find out which would be the best practice/efficient way to do.
I have a method where I have an OpenFileDialog. There I must use Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName) in 5 places inside the method. Which is the best way: either I call to GetFileName or save it in a string variable and then use that string variable?

```
" " + Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName) + " " 

string fileName = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName);
" " + fileName + " "
```

Comment: Is this an actual performance bottleneck? Unless it really is, I'd go for *which is more readable*. Otherwise, you should maybe have a look into `StringBuilder` too to make your string concatenations more efficient.

Comment: @Mudu I may be wrong here but wouldn't `String.Concat/String.Join` be better performing here? `StringBuilder` is better at concatenations within a loop (assuming this code isn't run within a loop).

Comment: @DGibbs The string concatenating using `+` is compiled to `string.Concat` in IL anyway..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead so i guess neither the `StringBuilder/Concat` will help in this case ;)

Comment: @DGibbs You may be right (I was assuming there is a loop, which is why I recommended `StringBuilder`). It was a bit silly to recommend Adrian optimising for *readability* and give some premature performance optimisation tips in the very same comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the considerations on readability and maintenance already outlined by other answers this little prog will demonstrate the (little) gain in performance of the string storing option

```
void Main()
{
    string p = @"d:\temp\file.txt";
    string result;

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        result = " " + Path.GetFileName(p) + " ";
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("PathGetFileName:" + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
    sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    string file = Path.GetFileName(p);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        result = " " + file + " ";
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("string concat:" + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
}
```

result:

```
PathGetFileName: 205632 

string concat: 65234
```

Of course, this is microoptimization and should not be given much consideration.
In this case the readability of code is more important.

Comment: In a realistic use case (i.e. one call to Path.GetFileName each time the OpenFileDialog.Show() is called) there won't be any difference. And I suspect the major part of the CPU time in your example to be used for string concatenation.

Comment: Absolutely true, but the string concatenation exists in both examples

Comment: regarding strings concatenation: should I use string.format or stringBuilder? which is most efficient?

Comment: @AlexaAdrian Again, you're micro-optimizing. Either one will be suitable unless you're processing hundreds of thousands/millions of pieces of data per second.

Comment: I just want to get used using best practices and in each day I am learning something new, so I want to fix this too :)

Comment: @AlexaAdrian - Try the example in the post but add a StringBuilder and see the results. Typically StringBuilder is better but it depends on the amount of loops (I assume due to the time it creates to make an instance of StringBuilder), but if the loop was 1000000000000 then I would guess StringBuilder is better, however, in this case I got faster results with string.

Comment: StringBuilder is better in this wicked case (100000 iterations), for small scale concatenations like the OP says it is Always more performant a simple string.Concat. (the + operator resolves to string.Concat internally) See some tests here http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-performance

Answer (score 2):

Just store the result of `Path.GetFileName` in a local variable.

It'll reduce the size of the code, be more readable (if the variable has a useful name) and will consume less CPU (even if you won't notice any difference).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the file-name at 5 places in the same method, use a local variable `fileName`. That's readable, efficient and without side effects.

If you may change the file often and it's a (public) property or field use `Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName)`, othwerwise it migt be possible that the variable is not the current file-name of the `openFileDialog`.

However, care more about readability and proper functioning than performance which is negligible in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same file name (eg, the user only specifies the file name once), then save it to a variable.

Saving it to a `string` is easier to read, maintain and should be quicker than calling the property of an object since you're calling a immutable reference type. However, I will point out that the only real advantage is probably that it's easier to read since calculation time may be different on paper but I doubt your application would show any differences in speed/performance.

Comment: Did you just say `string`'s are mutable.. ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes I did - the problem with fast typing! Thank you for pointing that out! Corrected!

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on reusing the filename in the same block of code/scope, then just save it to a string and reference that as needed. This is not only far more readable but also more memory efficient. E.g.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName);
//Reference fileName as needed
```